# Oracle, ROWNUM=1 with FOR UPDATE clause?

Tags: oracle

My statement:

```
SELECT ROW_ID DATA_T WHERE CITY_ID=2000 AND IS_FREE=0 AND ROWNUM = 1
```

is used to retrieve the first row for a db table that has many entries with CITY_ID equal to 2000.

The ROW_ID that is returned is then used in an UPDATE statement in order to use this row and set IS_FREE=1.

That worked very well until two threads called the SELECT statement and the got the same ROW_ID obviously... That is my problem in a few words.

I am using ORACLE DB (12.x)

How do I resolve the problem? Can I use FOR UPDATE in this case?

I want every "client" somehow to get a different row or at least lock on of them

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523189/concurrent-updates-in-oracle-locking-or-not

Comment: Why not try the pattern described here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8739488500346768428

Comment: So you are saying to do a "update DATA_T SET IS_FREE=1 where (SELECT ROW_ID DATA_T WHERE CITY_ID=2000 AND IS_FREE=0 AND ROWNUM = 1)

Comment: More like `UPDATE DATA_T SET IS_FREE=1 WHERE ROWID =
 (SELECT ROWID FROM DATA_T WHERE CITY_ID=2000 AND IS_FREE = 0 AND ROWNUM = 1) AND IS_FREE = 0 RETURNING ROWID INTO ridRowid_var`. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
   function get_row_id return number
   as
      cursor cur_upd is
         SELECT ROW_ID FROM TB WHERE CITY_ID=2000 AND IS_FREE=0 AND ROWNUM = 1
            FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
   begin
      for get_cur_upd in cur_upd
      loop
          update TB 
             set IS_FREE = 1
           where ROW_ID = get_cur_upd.ROW_ID;
          commit work;
          return get_cur_upd.ROW_ID;
      end loop;
      return null;
  end;
```

commit or not after update depends on your logic.

Also you can return row_id without update&commit and do it later outside func.